# Why doesn't my partial work with slim and Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, slim-lang

I'm using Rails 3.2 and instead of ERB, I am using `slim`.

Here is my form partial:

```
= simple_form_for @game, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
```

The syntax error I am getting is:

```
_form.html.slim:1: syntax error, unexpected ')' ... => 'form-horizontal' } do |f|))).to_s));
```

But I don't know where it expects to put the ')'?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The syntax should be:

> = form_for([@resource], html: { multipart: true }, remote: true) do |f|

Try substituting your values.

I was not able to find the correct documentation for slim form helper.